# Is it possible to insert <br> tag after every 5 words only on the string which has more than 5 words and also add <br> with "." (dot)

Tags: javascript

I want to insert `<br>`s into my string. Rules:

- Insert a `<br>` after every period.
- Insert a `<br>` after every 5 words.

For example:

```
This is a string. For demo to split the text. If its long more then 5 characters. But some string is short. And it will not split. the short length string it will only split the long string which is more then 5 words.";
```

Desired output:

```
This is a string.<br>For demo to split the<br>text.<br> If its long more then<br>5 characters.<br>But some string is short.<br>And it will not split.<br>The short length string it<br>will only split the long<br>string which is more then<br>5 words.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match either 5 non-space sequences (where the non-spaces don't include a `.`), or match a `.`. Then insert a `<br>` after the match:

```js
const str = "This is a string. For demo to split the text. If its long more then 5 characters. But some string is short. And it will not split. the short length string it will only split the long string which is more then 5 words.";

const output = str.replace(
  /(?:[^\s.]+\s+){5}|\./g,
  '$&<br>'
);
console.log(output);
```

`(?:[^\s.]+\s+){5}` - Repeat (non-space characters, followed by space characters) 5 times, where the non-space characters don't contain `.`

`\.` - Or, match a literal `.`

`'$&<br>'` - Replace with the matched string, concatenated with `<br>` after it

Note that your `str` is actually an array, not a string - more precise variable names improve code clarity and reduce bugs, you may wish to fix that.

Comment: I've updated the question please kindly help me again.

Comment: Since that was the last line so I do not need ```<br>``` there.

Comment: Oh I forgot it I'll update it now. Thats a mistake sorry

Comment: Use a negative character set to match non-spaces which aren't `.`s - or, match a `.`, and do the same replacement

Comment: can you please give an example? please

Comment: See the answer - you can press "Run code snippet"  in it to see it in action, if you want, it looks to produce the desired output

Comment: Sorry but I'm a newbie in this. I dont have good knowledge in RegEx. I would be very glad if you kindly solve this one. 